# access popup from browser extension

Tags: userscripts

I need to open a popup window and parse its contents.

I can do this from injected script as follows:
win = window.open(url);
$(win.document).find(...);

But this is blocked by popup blocker and user has to allow popups from the site.

If I do the same from the content script itself, then window is opened without being blocked, but win is undefined.

Is it possible at all to get contents of the popup window without being blocked by popup blocker?

Note that I open page from the same domain as the page the content script is called from.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Chrome Userscripts reference window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147623/google-chrome-userscripts-reference-window-open)

Comment: Ok, I open named window (which I actually do). How do I access its contents afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe or invisible iframe, if you don't want to show up iframe to users.

Append an iframe to document instead of opening a new window, then get contents of iframe.

```
$(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("#temp").append('<iframe id="tempiframe" 
                           src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/"></iframe>');
        $("#tempiframe").load(function() {
            alert("hey I get this from iframe\n" 
                   +$(this).contents().find("pre").html());
        });
    });
});​
```

[Here is a jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jXTXu/1/)

Comment: The site I'm opening doesn't work within iframe, so I have to use popup. I don't mind so much that it will be visible, but currently I don't even have access to it.